# button_Click(button, EventArgs.Empty);

Tags: c#, button, click

it doesn't work when my i put this:

```
if(label.text != " ")
{
    btn_Click(btn, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void btn_Click(obeject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    do something//
}
```

the button click function doesn't work

Comment: Why not put `do something//` in another method and call that instead?

Answer (score 4):

Its better if you can **extract the code in the event to a separate method** and then call that method, instead of raising the event.

```
private void btn_Click(obeject sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ExtractedMethod();
}

private void ExtractedMethod()
{
// do something
}

if(label.text != " ")
{
ExtractedMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean not

```
label.Text != " "
               ^-------------- space
```

try this:

```
if(label.Text != string.Empty())
{
   .....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if (label.text != " ")
{
    btn_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private void btn_Click(obeject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do something//
}
```